# How many words for I are there in Chinese?

Tags: word

I wonder how many words and pronunciations for **I** exist/existed in Chinese.

I know of these:

我：wǒ， but I believe it is pronounced **ngo** in Cantonese.

There seems to be an n-root for I in Chinese. I know, in 江苏泰州话， I = n

吾: wú also yù

余：yú

俺：ǎn （孙悟空说的“俺老空”）

Can you contribute any more **I**s， please?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share an interesting “I”, 朕.

In modern day (or post-Qin Dynasty) usage, 朕 was a first person pronoun reserved solely for the Emperor to refer to himself in front of all his subjects.

However, before the Qin Dynasty, 朕 was a word used by all commoners to refer to themselves, among the large variety of words which conveyed the same meaning. (予、僕、吾、我）

[屈原](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qu_Yuan), who lived in the Warring States period of the Zhou dynasty, wrote a poem called [离骚](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Sao). The first line says:

> 帝高阳之苗裔兮，朕皇考曰伯庸。

“(I am) a descendant of [帝高阳](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhuanxu), my (late) father’s name is 伯庸.”

Comment: In the same vein, 寡人、孤

Answer (score 3):

- **咱家**: often used in early vernacular literature

  - eg: 《红楼梦．第五六回》：「众丫鬟都笑道：『原来不是咱家的宝玉。』」
- **洒家**: (音zá) oral used around Song & Yuan Dynasty. “洒家”是宋元时代北方口语
- 在下, 鄙人, 不才, when introducing oneself to someone in same age
- 晚生、后生: 年轻者在年长者面前的自陈。young people saying 'I' to elder people.
- 老夫: 年长者在年轻者面前的自称，elder people saying 'I' to young.
- 不孝儿：儿子在父母面前的自称, son saying 'I' to parents
- 家: 用于对别人称自己的辈分高或年纪大的亲戚。如家父. introducing one's parent/elder relatives to others
- 舍: 用于对别人称自己的辈分低或年纪小的亲戚。如舍弟, introducing one's relatives with same ages to others
- 愚: 用于自称的谦称。如愚兄, introducing oneself
- 敝, 鄙: 用于谦称自己或跟自己有关的事物
- more at [here](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/64570086.html)

Answer (score 2):

**同源詞**

- 我 (Baxter-Sagart 上古漢語擬音: **/*ŋˤajʔ/**), 吾 (**/*ŋˤa/**)

  - (客家話)
  - 俺 (我 + 們)
  - 阮 (我 + 儂, 閩南語)
  - 阿拉 (「阿」同源于「我」, 「拉」是複數詞, 上海話)
  - 卬 (雙峰湘語)
  - 昂 (金華吳語)
- 予 (**/*laʔ/**), 余 (**/*la/**)

  - 朕 (**/*lrəmʔ/**, 皇帝自稱)
  - 台 (**/*lə/**, 普通話 **yí**)

**謙詞**

- 小人
- 臣
- 奴 (閩東語中是普通詞語)
- 儂 (同源于「人」, 文昌話)
- 僕, 婢

**文言中其他詞語**

- 私

Comment: Hi and thanks! zdic has for 阮：唐代读音：ngiuæ̌n Is that the correct sound for this character as I??

Comment: @Pedroski You're supposed to read it in the topolect that it's used in (閩南福建話, **gún** in [POJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pe%CC%8Dh-%C5%8De-j%C4%AB) Romanisation), not 唐代讀音. Have you tried Wiktionary? They're pretty comprehensive in the topolects they list there.